# workbook does not open when add in calls a userform at start up

Tags: excel, vba, startup, userform

I have an excel add in(xlam) which calls a userform when excel is opening.

When I now open an existing excel file, the userform show up as expected and I can click the "OK" button which closes the userform. Unfortunately afterwards, the workbook I intended to open **does not show up.**

- it is working with vbmodeless, so it seems to be connected to "hide" or "unload" of the userform
- when I open a new excel workbook it is working fine

Does anybody know why the workbook is not opening? Does excel forget the workbook he intended to open?

[image: code of the add in]

Comment: Can you post the code rather than screen shots please.  Thanks.  I think you've put the form opening in the add-in opening.

Comment: Yes - i thought a picture is more easy to understand when code is in different windows. To your question: yes - the whole code is in the add-in(xlam) and the userform is called in the add-in under "ThisWorkbook"

Comment: So this will only trigger on opening Excel, not each workbook.

Comment: sry but i am a bit puzzled. Maybe my aim is not clear: I have a toolbox with small programs for excel-->the add-in. When I open excel, the add in is called and I can use the toolbox in all workbooks. So it's enough when the toolbox is called with the first workbook. While opening the toolbox he should check for an update and if an update is available open a userform. If you reject the update, close the userform and open the workbook which I intended to open. But this workbook is not opening. I have to open it a second time because then the toolbox is not called again.(which is okay)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted the form to show each time a workbook was opening.   I have the following in my userform `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.Hide
Unload Me
End Sub` and this in my addin's `workbook_open`  `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub`

Comment: Yes - as I said vbmodeless is working but it would be interesting why it is not working with vbModal. And with vbModeless it is not necessary to open the workbook when you accept to update the toolbox and anyway the userform is finally behind the workbook. So its a question of "user experience" :-) - anyway: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your add-in you need to listen to Excel's events.  So you need to create a class, based on the Excel Application.

So you would have a class called `clsCustomExcelHandlers` like so

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ExcelApplication As Excel.Application

Private Sub ExcelApplication_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
        '   Do something here
        MsgBox "You have opened " & Wb.FullName
End Sub
```

and then in a standard module, have a public variable holding an instance of this class

`Public clsCustomExcel As clsCustomExcelHandlers`

and then in the add-in `Workbook_open` you set it up

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set clsCustomExcel = New clsCustomExcelHandlers
    Set clsCustomExcel.ExcelApplication = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: Sry - does not solve my problem - I want the form open just before the first workbook is opening and the problem is, that after the UF is called and then closed the workbook is not opening. - Thanks for your effort

Comment: No worries, misunderstood.  You could use this answer with a `if workbooks.count=0 then userform.show` ???